# Low-intermediate graded readers for Latin

Tags: resource-request, reading, graded-readers, latin

Which books can I use to progress in Latin reading once I have finished *Lingua Latina per se Illustrata: Colloquia Personarum*? The degree of difficulty should correspond more or less to the level you have once you have reached chapter XX of Hans Henning Ørberg's *Lingua latina per se illustrata*.

I've seen this [other question asking for reading resources](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/8956/) and I've read its answers, but there they are asking
for Latin texts to continue reading after highschool, that is, for a higher level than the one I'm asking for. It may be that some of the resources contained in its answers are appropriate for my level, the problem is that it is impossible for me to know this. So, I would like to receive an answer which specifically address the level I've specified: not an absolute beginner, nor an intermediate level, but something in   between. In addition, some of the links in the websites linked in the answers to the above linked question doesn't work.

I'm not looking for grammar books with some texts, but for something similar to graders readers.

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/reading-latin/A765F7394FE77C998E22B1549977F95B#overview

Comment: Thanks, @Lambie, but this seems to be a grammar book.

Comment: "it encourages the reading of continuous texts from the start" This does seem to correspond to your level. The main point is that it has full texts.